# Having two statements on one line

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, statements

Is there a possibility to have two statements on one line?

```
If .....
 Else
     Set rng = Nothing and exit Function
 End If
   .AutoFilterMode = False
 End With
```

Comment: I edited your tags, because your question seems to apply to Excel VBA, not pure Excel.

Comment: `:` is a continuation `Set rng = Nothing: exit Function` but readability is more important than brevity & imo two lines + an end if are preferable.

Comment: thank you. I have added some more statements